# Get Rid of Formly Warnings in Karma Output

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gulp, karma-jasmine, angular-formly

This is a problem at work, so any code I can share is limited. So far of three engineers, none of us has found a solution, and this is really a pain in our rear ends!

We've been working with [angular-formly](http://angular-formly.com/#/), but it just didn't meet our needs and had a lot of gaps. So, we installed [angular-formly-templates-bootstrap](https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly-templates-bootstrap) to fill said gaps. However, this overwrote some of the styling on our forms, and we received the following errors (I only copied a few of them; there are too many to count):

```
WARN: 'Formly Warning:', 'Attempting to overwrite radio on types which is currently {"template":"<md-radio-group ng-model=\"model[options.key]\" md-theme=\"{{to.theme}}\">\n    <md-radio-button\n            ng-repeat=\"option in to.options\"\n            ng-disabled=\"to.disabled\"\n            ng-value=\"option[to.valueProp || 'value']\">\n            {{option[to.labelProp || 'name']}}\n    </md-radio-button>\n</md-radio-group>\n","name":"radio","wrapper":["label"]} with {"name":"radio","template":"<div class=\"radio-group\">\n  <div ng-repeat=\"(key, option) in to.options\" class=\"radio\">\n    <label>\n      <input type=\"radio\"\n             id=\"{{id + '_'+ $index}}\"\n             tabindex=\"0\"\n             ng-value=\"option[to.valueProp || 'value']\"\n             ng-model=\"model[options.key]\">\n      {{option[to.labelProp || 'name']}}\n    </label>\n  </div>\n</div>\n","wrapper":["bootstrapLabel","bootstrapHasError"],"defaultOptions":{"noFormControl":false}} To supress this warning, specify the property "overwriteOk: true"', 'https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly/blob/8.2.0/other/ERRORS_AND_WARNINGS.md#overwriting-types-or-wrappers'
WARN: 'Formly Warning:', 'Attempting to overwrite select on types which is currently {"template":"<md-select ng-model=\"model[options.key]\" md-theme=\"{{to.theme}}\">\n    <md-option ng-repeat=\"option in to.options\" ng-value=\"option[to.valueProp || 'value']\">\n        {{ option[to.labelProp || 'name'] }}\n    </md-option>\n</md-select>\n","name":"select","wrapper":["label","messages","inputContainer"],"defaultOptions":{"templateOptions":{"disabled":false},"ngModelAttrs":{"disabled":{"bound":"ng-disabled"},"onClose":{"bound":"md-on-close"},"onOpen":{"bound":"md-on-open"}}}} with {"name":"select","template":"<select class=\"form-control\" ng-model=\"model[options.key]\"></select>","wrapper":["bootstrapLabel","bootstrapHasError"]} To supress this warning, specify the property "overwriteOk: true"', 'https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly/blob/8.2.0/other/ERRORS_AND_WARNINGS.md#overwriting-types-or-wrappers'
WARN: 'Formly Warning:', 'Attempting to overwrite textarea on types which is currently {"template":"<textarea ng-model=\"model[options.key]\"></textarea>","name":"textarea","wrapper":["label","messages","inputContainer"],"defaultOptions":{"ngModelAttrs":{"disabled":{"bound":"ng-disabled"},"rows":{"attribute":"rows"},"cols":{"attribute":"cols"}},"templateOptions":{"grow":true}}} with {"name":"textarea","template":"<textarea class=\"form-control\" ng-model=\"model[options.key]\"></textarea>","wrapper":["bootstrapLabel","bootstrapHasError"],"defaultOptions":{"ngModelAttrs":{"rows":{"attribute":"rows"},"cols":{"attribute":"cols"}}}} To supress this warning, specify the property "overwriteOk: true"', 'https://github.com/formly-js/angular-formly/blob/8.2.0/other/ERRORS_AND_WARNINGS.md#overwriting-types-or-wrappers'
```

*We only get 5 or so warnings in the browser, but we get absolutely overloaded in our Karma test output.*

So, obviously, we just have to put "overwriteOk: true" in our code somewhere, right? Well...no. Unfortunately, this only works when we inject this line into the *library*, which we aren't tracking in source control and would be overwritten with a bower install.

So it comes to this. Is there a way to ignore those warnings in our test output? We run our karma tests with gulp. We get **hundreds** of lines of just these warnings, which makes it impossible to find the actual errors when they occur.

We have already tried changing the logLevel in the Karma config, and that did not get rid of it. Even LOG_DISABLE didn't get rid of the warnings.

Does anybody have any ideas? We don't want to disable the styling (we like it better), just the warnings. If nobody can help us here, we're considering creating a pull request to angular-formly-templates-bootstrap with the overwriteOk: true lines in there.

Answer (score 0):

Straight out of the documentation:

### disableWarnings

Formly gives some useful warnings when you attempt to use a template that doesn't exist or there's a problem loading a template. You can disable these warnings via `formlyConfigProvider.disableWarnings = true`

http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/formlyconfig

Please mark this as the correct answer.